# Activating the genocide route

Tags: undertale

So I just finished true pacifist route, and I planned on doing the genocide route now. I understood that I must keep killing monsters until the "But nobody came" text comes and music changes, so i kept killing. I also slaughtered the dummy and the froggit that appeared during Toriel's "walkthrough", but it doesn't matter how many monsters I kill, the route wont activate. I have some questions about it.

1.Am I allowed to "kill" Napstablook if the genocide route is not activated yet?

2.Am I allowed to leave the first room (you know, with the monster candy room and a leaf pile in it)I left it and saved my file at the mouse hole part, but if I'm not allowed to exit the first room I guess I screwed up.

3.Can I complete the genocide route after a true reset? Or do I have to complete the neutral route first?

Comment: Typically, you should try to limit yourself to a single question per post.

Answer (score 1):

[Obvious Genocide route spoilers below]

To get on the Genocide route, you have to actively hunt for as many monsters as you can find. That means you have to kill not just the scripted monster encounters (such as the Froggit or Napstablook) but also a certain number of random monster encounters. Additionally, you have to make sure you kill enough monsters *before* you fight the boss of the area. For the Ruins, this is Toriel. Papyrus is the boss of Snowdin, Undyne for Waterfall, and Metatton NEO for Hotlands. If you don't kill enough monsters before killing the boss, you will get shifted to the Neutral route.

After you kill enough monsters in the Ruins (you'll know you've killed enough when you get the "But nobody came" message), all future save points will show you how many monsters you still need to kill for the current region you are in. Once you've killed enough monsters, the save points will simply say "Determination.".

As long as you follow these rules, you should stay on Genocide route.

Comment: Okay, so i successfully started the genocide route. I managed to kill monsters in snowdin forest until it said "1 left" in red text. Then I killed Greater dog. After that, the music went back to normal and save points now display the "That comedian..." message. Did i screw up?

Comment: Wait no, I already got it. I just used the continuous walking glitch to fing the last enemy. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex No problem. If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Well Alex if in Snowdin the SAVE point says "That comedian..." that means you have to go to Snowdin Forest and knock off Snowdrake. Not doing so will push you onto a Neutral route.

Comment: OP is asking about a much earlier point than this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer all of your questions:

1. You can 'kill' Napsta in the Genocide Run. You have to kill all scripted battles, though, and take out Snowdrake in Snowdin Forest along with a number of random encounters. Note that you don't have to kill EVERY monster, just enough to get the 'but nobody came' message in each area - this way, you could actively hunt for those with high EXP.
2. Yes, you can, but you must not fight Toriel until you get the 'but nobody came' message in the Ruins.
3. You can complete the Genocide Run as your first run without needing to do a Neutral Run first.